# Schedule the call of a method at different times using different parameters

Tags: c#, .net

I have an XML file that defines the times at which a method should be called, as well as the arguments to be passed to the method at each call. 
Question is, how to schedule the calling of the method at the desired times and using the desired arguments?
I have seen The [Task.Dealy()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx) method but it does not help in this case. As I have to calculate the difference between each two times in the xml file. I think there should be some easier way to do it.

What I am looking for is something like this:
at 15:30 on 5th of July call the method by passing argument1
Then at 18:00 on 5th of July call the method by passing argument2

Comment: Ah, the perennial questions.

Comment: There are dozens of duplicates already. You can use Windows Scheduled Tasks or you can create your own service that uses a library like Quartz.net or Hangfire to schedule tasks. Most of the time though Scheduled Tasks are more than enough